# Perform simple math on regular expression output? (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to perform simple math on the output from Python regular expressions?

I have a large file where I need to divide numbers following a `")"` by 100.  For instance, I would convert the following line containing `)75` and `)2`:

```
((words:0.23)75:0.55(morewords:0.1)2:0.55);
```

to `)0.75` and `)0.02`:

```
((words:0.23)0.75:0.55(morewords:0.1)0.02:0.55);
```

My first thought was to use `re.sub` using the search expression `"\)\d+"`, but I don't know how to divide the integer following the parenthesis by 100, or if this is even possible using `re`.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried converting the string to an integer?

Comment: Regex are for text manipulation. To achieve I don't see any escape from converting the string to integer and than dividing it by 100.

Comment: Incidentally, this looks like it is in Newick format (except that in Newick format you wouldn't normally have a bootstrap confidence on a single node like `words` or `morewords`). You might have an easier time doing other operations using a Newick parser, like the [one in BioPython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc165), rather than regex.

Comment: Yes, you're correct -- I'm dividing the bootstrap values in a Newick tree by 100.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it by providing a function as the replacement:

```
s = "((words:0.23)75:0.55(morewords:0.1)2:0.55);"

s = re.sub("\)(\d+)", lambda m: ")" + str(float(m.groups()[0]) / 100), s)

print s
# ((words:0.23)0.75:0.55(morewords:0.1)0.02:0.55);
```

Incidentally, if you wanted to do it using [BioPython's Newick tree parser](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc165) instead, it would look like this:

```
from Bio import Phylo
# assuming you want to read from a string rather than a file
from StringIO import StringIO

tree = Phylo.read(StringIO(s), "newick")

for c in tree.get_nonterminals():
    if c.confidence != None:
        c.confidence = c.confidence / 100

print tree.format("newick")
```

(while this particular operation takes more lines than the regex version, other operations involving trees might be made much easier with it).

Answer (score 1):

The replacement expression for `re.sub` can be a function.  Write a function that takes the matched text, converts it to a number, divides it by 100, and then returns the string form of the result.